# Python ImportError: No module named pygments

Tags: python, import, pygments

I ran the following code

```
# Allows the use of display() for displaying 
from IPython.display import display DataFrames
```

It displayed the following **error**:

```
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/colorable.py", line 13, in <module>
    import pygments
ImportError: No module named pygments
```

So I tried installing `pygments`:

```
pip install pygments
```

and it says:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in /home/rico/downloads/hgvs-0.1.2/Pygments-2.1.3-py2.7.egg (2.1.3)
```

Do you have an idea how to resolve this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: Not so much a Linux user, but something looks wonky with `/home/rico/downloads/hgvs-0.1.2/Pygments-2.1.3-py2.7.egg (2.1.3)`. It's installed in your downloads folder?

Comment: Do you use virtualenv? The path pip tells you does seem very weird. My path shows me `/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages`.
Also, try `sudo pip install Pygments`, this should ignore the "installation" in your downloads folder.

Comment: @MarcelP doesn't that just install into the system python?

Comment: pip install Pygments ==> Requirement already satisfied: Pygments in home/rico/downloads/hgvs-0.1.2/Pygments-2.1.3-py2.7.egg (2.1.3). It says the same thing

Comment: I don't use virtualenv. Should I use it?

Comment: It should install into system, at least I understood it like that.
virtualenv would _kinda_ explain the rather weird path. Did you try to remove it and install it again to see if it still resides in the same directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you installed the *Pygments* module on the global scope instead of installing inside a *virtualenv*.

#### What is a virtual environment?

Virtual environments are a way to keep your dependencies inline for your app or service. 
`virtualenv` is a tool to create isolated Python environments, in which you can now install dependencies specific for that environment rather than installing them globally.

Virtual environments help create consistency in your development and deployment process, which in turn will help build a better app or service.

#### Installing virtualenv

First, Install virtual env:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

To create a virtualenv first run this command:

```
$ virtualenv -p python3 {name-of-virtual-env}
```

Lets call it `my_venv`, so ran the following command:

```
$ virtualenv -p python3 my_venv
```

Once you create the virtual environment, run the following to activate it:

```
$ source my_venv/bin/activate
```

After running the activate command you should see the name of your virtual env at the beginning of your terminal like this:

```
(my_venv) $ source my_venv/bin/activate
```

#### Installing modules locally

Navigate inside the `my_venv` folder and install the *Pygments* module:

```
cd my_venv && pip3 install pygments
```

You should see it was installed localy under `lib/python3.8/site-packages` inside the `my_venv` folder:

```
`-- my_venv
    |-- bin
    |-- lib
    |   `-- python3.8
    |       `-- site-packages
    |           |-- chardet
    |           |-- chardet-3.0.4.dist-info
    |           |-- idna
    |           |-- pip
    |           |-- pip-21.0.1.dist-info
    |           |-- pip-21.0.1.virtualenv
    |           |-- pkg_resources
    |           |-- pygments #<--------- Here
    |           |-- pygments_promql            
    |           |-- pygments_promql-0.0.5.dist-info
    |           |-- regex
    `-- pyvenv.cfg
```

#### Deactivate virtualenv

When you are done running your app or service, you can shutdown your virtualenv by running the deactivate command:

```
(my_venv) $ deactivate
```

---

Read more in [here](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/).